# Count number of extrema in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 481 integers in Oracle table. Their values change randomly and it can be represented like a function where x changes from 1 to 481 and y changes from 0 to 15. How can I count number of all local maximum and minimum points (extrema) for these numbers?

Comment: Please edit the question, and show example data and expected output and what you have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no ties, you can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select sum(case when y > prev_y and y > next_y then 1 else 0 end) as local_maxima,
       sum(case when y < prev_y and y < next_y then 1 else 0 end) as local_minima
from (select t.*,
             lag(y) over (order by x) as prev_y,
             lead(y) over (order by x) as next_y
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon! It was very helpful and instructive.